# Route parameters are undefined in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to pass the name of an album so that when the user clicks on a certain album, they go to its page
However, my route parameters are always receiving the value undefined in my albumName, does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Here is my component that when clicked, the user goes to the album details page:

**ListWithProgress.tsx**

```
import {
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

interface AlbumStarted {
  id: string;
  albumName: string;
  image: string;
  progress: number;
  album: {
    song: string;
    listened: boolean;
    rating: number;
  }[];
}

interface ListWithProgressProps {
  data: AlbumStarted[];
}

const ListWithProgress = ({ data }: ListWithProgressProps) => {
  const numColumns = 3;
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleImagePress = (albumName: string) => {
    navigation.navigate("albumsDetails", { albumName: "Album name" });
  };

  const renderItem = ({
    item,
  }: {
    item: {
      id: string;
      albumName: string;
      image: string;
      progress: number;
      album: {
        song: string;
        listened: boolean;
        rating: number;
      }[];
    };
  }) => (
    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.6}
        onPress={() => handleImagePress(item.albumName)}
      >
        <Image source={item.image} style={styles.image} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.progressBar}>
        <View
          style={[styles.progressGreen, { width: `${item.progress * 100}%` }]}
        />
        <View
          style={[
            styles.progressGray,
            { width: `${(1 - item.progress) * 100}%` },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item: any) => item.id.toString()}
      numColumns={numColumns}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
    />
  );
};

export default ListWithProgress;
```

And here is my album details page, which should show the value received in the navigate() function, but the value is never being shown

**albumDetails.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/native";

const AlbumDetailsScreen: React.FC = ({ route }) => {
  if (!route || !route.params) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Name:</Text>
        <Text style={styles.albumName}>Album not found</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  const { albumName } = route.params;

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Name:</Text>
      <Text style={styles.albumName}>{albumName}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AlbumDetailsScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 32,
    top: 100,
  },
  albumName: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 24,
  },
});
```